# query to combine questions with options from two different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two database tables:

`Definitions` table has the following columns:

```
Id, Category
```

Sample data:

```
1, What is capital of USA ?
2, Who broke my glass ?
```

`Options` table has the following columns:

```
Id, DefinitionId, Value
```

Sample Data:

```
1, 1, New York
2, 1, Melbourne
3, 1, Lahore
4, 2, Boss
5, 2, My brother
6, 2, Your girlfriend
```

Please guide me how I can query ALL questions with All options, I need data like below:

```
"", 1, What is capital of USA ?
1,1, New York
2,1, Melbourne
3, 1, Lahore

"", 2,Who broke my glass ?
4, 2, Boss
5, 2, My brother
6, 2, Your girlfriend
```

Please guide

Comment: It is "impossible" to create this type of output as the datatype of the first column is string (first row) and then an integer (following rows). This could be achieved in MSSQL using the sql_variant type, but I bet this is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, use `UNION ALL` like so:

```
SELECT '' ID, DefinitionId, Category AS value FROM Definitions WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, DefinitionId, Value FROM Options WEHRE DefentionID = 1;
```

**Note that:** it is better to `JOIN` the two tables like so:

```
SELECT 
  d.Id,
  o.Id,
  o.Value
FROM Definitions d
INNER JOIN Options o ON d.ID = o.DefinitionId
WHERE d.Id = 1;
```

And don't consider to do this formatting in SQL;

**Update:** To get all questions, try this:

```
SELECT '' ID, ID AS DefinitionId, Category AS value FROM Definitions 
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, DefinitionId, Value FROM Options
ORDER BY DEFINITIONID, ID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a355/7)

This will give you:

```
| ID | DEFINITIONID |                    VALUE |
------------------------------------------------
|  0 |            1 | What is capital of USA ? |
|  1 |            1 |                 New York |
|  2 |            1 |                Melbourne |
|  3 |            1 |                   Lahore |
|  0 |            2 |     Who broke my glass ? |
|  4 |            2 |                     Boss |
|  5 |            2 |               My brother |
|  6 |            2 |          Your girlfriend |
```

Comment: can you please see my edit I need all sets of data not just one. Please guide

Comment: If you display your data using a report generator, consider using Mahmoud's second approach and group by the o.Id-Column. This way you could also list all questions and their possible answers in one go and create something like a multiple choice paper.

Comment: double quotes is not allowed in sql server. Change it to single quotes with space.

Comment: @Pranav - Yes, you are right. It is invalid in this way. Updated, Thanks. But it  is allowed to specify an identifier name, it is the same as `[]` but it is the standard way to do this. See the demo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To display your data like you asked, you can also use something like a pivot table in Excel with your database as the source. This also works well with Sql Server Analysis Services.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ' ',D.ID,D.category from Definitions D where D.Id = 1
UNION 
SELECT C.ID,C.DefinitionId,C.Value from options C where C.DefinitionId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  NULL,D.Id,D.Category
FROM    Definitions D
UNION
SELECT  O.Id,O.DefinitionId,O.Value
FROM    Options O
ORDER BY 2,1
```